# C++ : grandchild class has no implementation of virtual function of both child & parent class, program works

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual

I was just revising the basic concepts of OOP and I ran across this. The program works but I can not understand why it works. I have a base class `Vehicle` and child class `Car` and Grandchild class `TwoDoorCar`. The code is given below:

```
class Vehicle {
private:
   int wheels;
   string make;
protected:
  int protect;
public:
virtual ~Vehicle(){}
Vehicle(){
    cout << "empty Vehicle constructor" << endl;
    this->wheels = 0;
    this->make = "";
    this->protect = 0;
}

Vehicle(int wheel,string m){
    cout << "parametrized Vehicle constructor" << endl;
    this->wheels = wheel;
    this->make = m;
    this->protect = 0;
}

void ctest() const{ // read only function
    cout << "ctest() called" << endl;
}

virtual void Drive() = 0;

const string& getMake() const {
    return make;
}

void setMake(const string& make) {
    this->make = make;
}

int getWheels() const {
    return wheels;
}

void setWheels(int wheels) {
    this->wheels = wheels;
}
};

class Car : virtual public Vehicle {
private:
int carNumber;
public:
virtual ~Car(){}
Car():Vehicle(){
    cout << "empty car constructor" << endl;
    carNumber = 0;
}

Car(int wheels, string make, int Number) : Vehicle(wheels,make){
    cout << "Car's constructor called" << endl;
    this->carNumber = Number;
}

Car(int wh, string m): Vehicle(wh, m){
    this->carNumber = 0;
}

virtual void Drive(){
    cout << "Car driven " << endl;
}

virtual void Drive(string p){
    cout << "Over loaded function of Drive with string argument : " << p << endl;
}

void testProtect(){
    cout << "Car::Protected member " << this->protect << endl;
}
};

class TwoDoorCar : public Car{
public:
virtual ~TwoDoorCar(){}
TwoDoorCar():Car(){
    cout << "Empty two door car constructor" << endl;
}

TwoDoorCar(int wheels, string make, int reg) : Car(wheels,make,reg){

}

};
```

The pure virtual function `Drive()` is defined in the child class but not in the grandchild class. I tried using `virtual` in the child class, yet the program works with no function implementation of the `Drive()` function in the grandchild class.

I run with the following code

```
TwoDoorCar tdc1;
Vehicle * v3 = &tdc1;
v3->Drive();
```

The output of the program is

```
empty Vehicle constructor
empty car constructor
Empty two door car constructor
Car driven
```

Can anyone explain why there is no error here even though pure virtual and virtual are used in base and child class respectively?

Comment: It uses the `Car::Drive` function.

Comment: Once a pure virtual function is implemented it's no longer required to be implemented in further derived classes.

Comment: Did you really have to dump so much code on us to illustrate this simple issue? Consider the *minimal* aspect of a [mcve].

Comment: Okay sorry my bad but I didn't want anything to be left out. 
But the child class has the virtual function too , shouldn't it be required to have an implementation in the granchild class?

Comment: Why do you expect this to be an error?

Comment: _"shouldn't it be required to have an implementation in the granchild class?"_ No, as I've already mentioned that's not required.

Comment: That's kind of how inheritance is supposed to work, as a way for *specialization*. A `TwoDoorCar` is still a `Car`, why should its `Drive` functionality be different from that of a `Car`?

Comment: @FarhanJaved Your code could be reduced to https://ideone.com/5vEt09.

Answer (score 1):

Only pure virtual functions are required to be defined. virtual functions can be derived by inherited classes and does not require to be re-defined in inherited class.